# pandas DataFrame replace() by using regex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a pandas DataFrame `df`. I want to replace `↑`(a space after ↑) with `+`, and `↓`(a space after ↓) with `-`. For example, `df.a[0]`(values `↑ 0.69%`) replace with `+0.69%`.

`df['last_month'] = df['last_month'].replace(r"↑ ","")`is not right. Why?

```
data = [{"a":"↑ 0.69%","b":"↓ 9.93%"},{"a":"↓ 0.46%","b":"↑ 3.3%"},{"a":"↓ 0.78%","b":"↓ 3.43%"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    a         b
0   ↑ 0.69%   ↓ 9.93%
1   ↓ 0.46%   ↑ 3.3%
2   ↓ 0.78%   ↓ 3.43%
```

---

In my raw data, `↑` is an unicode, so it didn't work. In the demo data, `↑` is a str(bytes), so `df['last_month'] = df['last_month'].replace(r"↑ ","")` works actually like MaxU's. But how to replace when DataFrame values are unicode?

Comment: not right? can you create a [mcve]? and this is not regex this is string replacement.

Comment: could you post a __reproducible__ data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [28]: df.replace(['↑\s*', '↓\s*'], ['+', '-'], regex=True)
Out[28]:
        a       b
0  +0.69%  -9.93%
1  -0.46%   +3.3%
2  -0.78%  -3.43%
```

For Python 2x:

```
In [80]: %paste
data = [{"a":u"↑ 0.69%","b":u"↓ 9.93%"},{"a":u"↓ 0.46%","b":u"↑ 3.3%"},{"a":u"↓ 0.78%","b":u"↓ 3.43%"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
## -- End pasted text --
Out[80]:
         a        b
0  ↑ 0.69%  ↓ 9.93%
1  ↓ 0.46%   ↑ 3.3%
2  ↓ 0.78%  ↓ 3.43%

In [81]: %paste
df = df.replace([u'↑\s*', u'↓\s*'], [u'+', u'-'], regex=True)
print(df)
## -- End pasted text --
        a       b
0  +0.69%  -9.93%
1  -0.46%   +3.3%
2  -0.78%  -3.43%
```

Comment: `df.replace(['↑\s*', '↓\s*'], ['+', '-'], regex=True)` works if `↑`is a bytes but not an unicode? What if `↑`is an unicode?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.12 @MaxU

Answer (score 2):

you can `stack` then `unstack` with the `str` accessor.

```
df.stack().str.replace("↑ ","+").str.replace("↓ ", "-").unstack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it, `df.replace([u'↑ ', u'↓ '], [u'+', u'-'], regex=True)` works.